# Google Map - Get location of marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm having 2 polygon `{ "Country": "01", "Location": "09", "City": "156" }` and `{ "Country": "01", "Location": "09", "City": "160" }`

I created a `centerMarker` fixed center the map. When user drag or change center the map. I will get position of `centerMarker`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle', function() {
    console.log(map.getCenter().lat());
    console.log(map.getCenter().lng());
  });
  $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())
```

How can I check `centerMarker` located on `"City": "160"` or `"City": "156"`?

My full code

```
function initMap() {
    var x = new google.maps.LatLng(11.200845,106.5746263,17);
    var data = 
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "name":"gadm36_VNM_3",
   "crs":{  
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{  
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Country":"01",
            "Location":"09",
            "City":"156"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  [  
                     [  
                        106.773910522460994,
                        11.140744209289601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764717102050994,
                        11.140742301941
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764862060547003,
                        11.1326341629028
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.763977050780994,
                        11.128930091857899
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.762413024902003,
                        11.1263284683228
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.761451721190994,
                        11.126066207885801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.760833740234006,
                        11.1245851516725
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.75707244873,
                        11.122723579406699
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.750144958495994,
                        11.1217250823975
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.747901916504006,
                        11.122282028198301
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.748207092285,
                        11.1209669113159
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.746643066405994,
                        11.1184997558594
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.746650695800994,
                        11.1169691085815
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.743644714355995,
                        11.1138353347779
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.742393493652003,
                        11.1109828948975
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737831115722997,
                        11.108716964721699
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737289428710994,
                        11.1100120544434
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737907409667997,
                        11.113375663757299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.73681640625,
                        11.114133834839
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737213134765994,
                        11.114882469177299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735412597655994,
                        11.116992950439499
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735473632812997,
                        11.1183891296387
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737617492675994,
                        11.119469642639199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737586975097997,
                        11.1202993392944
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735694885254006,
                        11.120556831359901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.736740112305,
                        11.1254129409791
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735290527344006,
                        11.1279869079591
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.73600769043,
                        11.132244110107401
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735633850097997,
                        11.1326360702516
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.733108520507997,
                        11.131629943847701
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.732345581055,
                        11.1364440917969
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.72779083252,
                        11.136043548583901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.727645874024006,
                        11.138410568237299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.724494934082003,
                        11.136935234069901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.718818664550994,
                        11.142228126526
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.716232299805,
                        11.1407585144044
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.713203430175994,
                        11.1368913650513
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.71263885498,
                        11.1488819122315
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.713729858399006,
                        11.1516876220704
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.725151062012003,
                        11.180347442626999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.734558105469006,
                        11.1816873550416
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.736030578612997,
                        11.180858612060501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.755981445312997,
                        11.1822462081909
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.761962890625,
                        11.1883802413941
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.762916564942003,
                        11.1905174255372
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764389038085994,
                        11.189139366149799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.76416015625,
                        11.188378334045501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.790100097655994,
                        11.1885118484497
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.792953491210994,
                        11.192991256713899
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.794372558594006,
                        11.1930904388429
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.794372558594006,
                        11.193788528442299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.796928405762003,
                        11.1949625015259
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.798072814940994,
                        11.194272994995099
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.803909301757997,
                        11.1985483169556
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.805290222167997,
                        11.198659896850501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.811401367187003,
                        11.202071189880501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.813606262207003,
                        11.205387115478599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.818145751952997,
                        11.2080841064453
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.819854736327997,
                        11.2152719497682
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823463439940994,
                        11.2161722183228
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.824119567870994,
                        11.213012695312401
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.828521728515994,
                        11.209532737731999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.831550598145,
                        11.209297180175801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835960388184006,
                        11.2118206024169
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835075378417997,
                        11.2105274200441
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837257385254006,
                        11.2098264694213
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.83716583252,
                        11.2090320587159
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836235046387003,
                        11.2091836929322
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837463378905994,
                        11.207406044006399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836402893065994,
                        11.2071533203125
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835906982422003,
                        11.2056436538696
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836585998535,
                        11.204249382019199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837699890137003,
                        11.2045288085938
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836631774902003,
                        11.2030754089356
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837547302245994,
                        11.2036037445068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.838134765625,
                        11.201634407043599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837783813477003,
                        11.199815750122101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836570739745994,
                        11.1994781494141
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.83723449707,
                        11.1985836029053
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835731506347997,
                        11.197198867798001
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835334777832003,
                        11.1953115463257
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.831237792969006,
                        11.193099975586
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.824752807617003,
                        11.196343421936101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821243286132997,
                        11.195686340331999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.818969726562997,
                        11.19251537323
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.81795501709,
                        11.192292213439901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.817756652832003,
                        11.190671920776399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.81111907959,
                        11.1809148788453
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.811645507812003,
                        11.178315162658601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.809783935547003,
                        11.1756134033203
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.809677124022997,
                        11.174137115478599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.807357788085994,
                        11.1731281280518
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.805305480957003,
                        11.169690132141101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.800598144530994,
                        11.1647386550903
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.791679382324006,
                        11.1622724533082
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.787879943847997,
                        11.163525581359799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.778388977050994,
                        11.1562852859497
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.773651123047003,
                        11.155713081359799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.773910522460994,
                        11.140744209289601
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Country":"01",
            "Location":"09",
            "City":"160"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  [  
                     [  
                        106.908004760742003,
                        11.129010200500399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.903732299805,
                        11.125083923339799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.887130737305,
                        11.1172142028809
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.882217407227003,
                        11.1076774597168
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.880096435547003,
                        11.101813316345201
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.87996673584,
                        11.0955753326416
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.876556396484006,
                        11.095563888549901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.876106262207003,
                        11.093448638916099
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.87442779541,
                        11.0930519104004
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.870147705077997,
                        11.093951225280801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.866645812987997,
                        11.093237876892101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.860298156737997,
                        11.0947256088256
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.858062744140994,
                        11.0945234298707
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856292724609006,
                        11.0934009552003
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.853942871094006,
                        11.0938158035279
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.850006103515994,
                        11.092667579650801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.848297119140994,
                        11.0912990570068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.845809936522997,
                        11.091200828552299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.842636108399006,
                        11.0886402130128
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.839897155762003,
                        11.0885286331178
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836471557617003,
                        11.086883544921999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.833183288574006,
                        11.087131500244199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.828132629395,
                        11.088861465454199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.825546264647997,
                        11.0915222167969
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823066711425994,
                        11.0958919525146
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823875427245994,
                        11.1021842956544
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.822807312012003,
                        11.107276916504
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.822982788085994,
                        11.1099071502687
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821441650390994,
                        11.1121578216553
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821563720702997,
                        11.1142129898072
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.829162597655994,
                        11.1119136810303
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856956481934006,
                        11.1134729385375
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856575012207003,
                        11.116441726684601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.858283996582003,
                        11.1262016296387
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.864997863769005,
                        11.1320905685425
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.871109008789006,
                        11.1428709030153
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.878143310547003,
                        11.143126487731999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.880805969237997,
                        11.144726753234901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.886619567870994,
                        11.1450748443604
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.889801025390994,
                        11.1470909118653
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.892097473145,
                        11.1469631195068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.896003723145,
                        11.145208358764799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.89820098877,
                        11.143099784851101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.898323059082003,
                        11.1416568756104
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900520324707003,
                        11.138403892516999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900169372559006,
                        11.1379747390747
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.901206970215,
                        11.137484550476101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900978088379006,
                        11.136289596557599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.902084350585994,
                        11.135934829711999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.902717590332003,
                        11.1330337524415
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.904357910155994,
                        11.1320133209229
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.905548095702997,
                        11.129722595214799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.907104492187997,
                        11.1286296844484
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.908004760742003,
                        11.129010200500399
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }

   ]
};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
    center: x,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle', function() {
    console.log(map.getCenter().lat());
    console.log(map.getCenter().lng());
  });
  $('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo(map.getDiv())

    map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to figure out if the center of your map is located inside polygon of the city you can use a geometry library of Maps JavaScript API. The geometry library provides method `containsLocation(point, polygon)` which may be useful for you. Have a look at the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly

First you have to include geometry library in the script tag that loads Maps JavaScript API adding the `&libraries=geometry` in the URL of Maps JavaScript API. Second, you create polygons of cities using the GeoJSON objects of data layer, so you have to convert multipolygons of data layer to google.maps.Polygons objects in order to use aforementioned method `containsLocation(point, polygon)`.

I recommend investigating documentation to see how you can convert these objects

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.MultiPolygon

Here is a sample code that makes a conversion of Multipolygons and uses `containsLocation(point, polygon)` to check if map center is inside a city polygon

```js
var map;
  function initMap() {
    var x = new google.maps.LatLng(11.200845,106.5746263,17);
    var data = 
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "name":"gadm36_VNM_3",
   "crs":{  
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{  
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Country":"01",
            "Location":"09",
            "City":"156"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  [  
                     [  
                        106.773910522460994,
                        11.140744209289601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764717102050994,
                        11.140742301941
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764862060547003,
                        11.1326341629028
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.763977050780994,
                        11.128930091857899
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.762413024902003,
                        11.1263284683228
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.761451721190994,
                        11.126066207885801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.760833740234006,
                        11.1245851516725
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.75707244873,
                        11.122723579406699
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.750144958495994,
                        11.1217250823975
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.747901916504006,
                        11.122282028198301
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.748207092285,
                        11.1209669113159
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.746643066405994,
                        11.1184997558594
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.746650695800994,
                        11.1169691085815
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.743644714355995,
                        11.1138353347779
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.742393493652003,
                        11.1109828948975
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737831115722997,
                        11.108716964721699
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737289428710994,
                        11.1100120544434
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737907409667997,
                        11.113375663757299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.73681640625,
                        11.114133834839
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737213134765994,
                        11.114882469177299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735412597655994,
                        11.116992950439499
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735473632812997,
                        11.1183891296387
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737617492675994,
                        11.119469642639199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.737586975097997,
                        11.1202993392944
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735694885254006,
                        11.120556831359901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.736740112305,
                        11.1254129409791
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735290527344006,
                        11.1279869079591
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.73600769043,
                        11.132244110107401
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.735633850097997,
                        11.1326360702516
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.733108520507997,
                        11.131629943847701
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.732345581055,
                        11.1364440917969
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.72779083252,
                        11.136043548583901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.727645874024006,
                        11.138410568237299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.724494934082003,
                        11.136935234069901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.718818664550994,
                        11.142228126526
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.716232299805,
                        11.1407585144044
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.713203430175994,
                        11.1368913650513
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.71263885498,
                        11.1488819122315
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.713729858399006,
                        11.1516876220704
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.725151062012003,
                        11.180347442626999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.734558105469006,
                        11.1816873550416
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.736030578612997,
                        11.180858612060501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.755981445312997,
                        11.1822462081909
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.761962890625,
                        11.1883802413941
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.762916564942003,
                        11.1905174255372
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.764389038085994,
                        11.189139366149799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.76416015625,
                        11.188378334045501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.790100097655994,
                        11.1885118484497
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.792953491210994,
                        11.192991256713899
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.794372558594006,
                        11.1930904388429
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.794372558594006,
                        11.193788528442299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.796928405762003,
                        11.1949625015259
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.798072814940994,
                        11.194272994995099
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.803909301757997,
                        11.1985483169556
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.805290222167997,
                        11.198659896850501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.811401367187003,
                        11.202071189880501
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.813606262207003,
                        11.205387115478599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.818145751952997,
                        11.2080841064453
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.819854736327997,
                        11.2152719497682
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823463439940994,
                        11.2161722183228
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.824119567870994,
                        11.213012695312401
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.828521728515994,
                        11.209532737731999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.831550598145,
                        11.209297180175801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835960388184006,
                        11.2118206024169
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835075378417997,
                        11.2105274200441
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837257385254006,
                        11.2098264694213
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.83716583252,
                        11.2090320587159
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836235046387003,
                        11.2091836929322
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837463378905994,
                        11.207406044006399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836402893065994,
                        11.2071533203125
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835906982422003,
                        11.2056436538696
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836585998535,
                        11.204249382019199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837699890137003,
                        11.2045288085938
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836631774902003,
                        11.2030754089356
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837547302245994,
                        11.2036037445068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.838134765625,
                        11.201634407043599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.837783813477003,
                        11.199815750122101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836570739745994,
                        11.1994781494141
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.83723449707,
                        11.1985836029053
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835731506347997,
                        11.197198867798001
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.835334777832003,
                        11.1953115463257
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.831237792969006,
                        11.193099975586
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.824752807617003,
                        11.196343421936101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821243286132997,
                        11.195686340331999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.818969726562997,
                        11.19251537323
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.81795501709,
                        11.192292213439901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.817756652832003,
                        11.190671920776399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.81111907959,
                        11.1809148788453
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.811645507812003,
                        11.178315162658601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.809783935547003,
                        11.1756134033203
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.809677124022997,
                        11.174137115478599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.807357788085994,
                        11.1731281280518
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.805305480957003,
                        11.169690132141101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.800598144530994,
                        11.1647386550903
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.791679382324006,
                        11.1622724533082
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.787879943847997,
                        11.163525581359799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.778388977050994,
                        11.1562852859497
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.773651123047003,
                        11.155713081359799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.773910522460994,
                        11.140744209289601
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Country":"01",
            "Location":"09",
            "City":"160"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [  
                  [  
                     [  
                        106.908004760742003,
                        11.129010200500399
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.903732299805,
                        11.125083923339799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.887130737305,
                        11.1172142028809
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.882217407227003,
                        11.1076774597168
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.880096435547003,
                        11.101813316345201
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.87996673584,
                        11.0955753326416
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.876556396484006,
                        11.095563888549901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.876106262207003,
                        11.093448638916099
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.87442779541,
                        11.0930519104004
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.870147705077997,
                        11.093951225280801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.866645812987997,
                        11.093237876892101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.860298156737997,
                        11.0947256088256
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.858062744140994,
                        11.0945234298707
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856292724609006,
                        11.0934009552003
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.853942871094006,
                        11.0938158035279
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.850006103515994,
                        11.092667579650801
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.848297119140994,
                        11.0912990570068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.845809936522997,
                        11.091200828552299
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.842636108399006,
                        11.0886402130128
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.839897155762003,
                        11.0885286331178
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.836471557617003,
                        11.086883544921999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.833183288574006,
                        11.087131500244199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.828132629395,
                        11.088861465454199
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.825546264647997,
                        11.0915222167969
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823066711425994,
                        11.0958919525146
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.823875427245994,
                        11.1021842956544
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.822807312012003,
                        11.107276916504
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.822982788085994,
                        11.1099071502687
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821441650390994,
                        11.1121578216553
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.821563720702997,
                        11.1142129898072
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.829162597655994,
                        11.1119136810303
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856956481934006,
                        11.1134729385375
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.856575012207003,
                        11.116441726684601
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.858283996582003,
                        11.1262016296387
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.864997863769005,
                        11.1320905685425
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.871109008789006,
                        11.1428709030153
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.878143310547003,
                        11.143126487731999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.880805969237997,
                        11.144726753234901
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.886619567870994,
                        11.1450748443604
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.889801025390994,
                        11.1470909118653
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.892097473145,
                        11.1469631195068
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.896003723145,
                        11.145208358764799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.89820098877,
                        11.143099784851101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.898323059082003,
                        11.1416568756104
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900520324707003,
                        11.138403892516999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900169372559006,
                        11.1379747390747
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.901206970215,
                        11.137484550476101
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.900978088379006,
                        11.136289596557599
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.902084350585994,
                        11.135934829711999
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.902717590332003,
                        11.1330337524415
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.904357910155994,
                        11.1320133209229
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.905548095702997,
                        11.129722595214799
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.907104492187997,
                        11.1286296844484
                     ],
                     [  
                        106.908004760742003,
                        11.129010200500399
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
         }
      }

   ]
};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
        center: x,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: x,
      map: map
    });
    
    var features = map.data.addGeoJson(data);
    var mapPolies = new Map();
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
     var city = feature.getProperty("City");
      var geom = feature.getGeometry();
      var polygons = geom.getArray();
      var polys = [];
      polygons.forEach(function(polygon) {
        var paths = [];
        var linearRings = polygon.getArray();
        linearRings.forEach(function(linearRing){
          var coords = linearRing.getArray();
          paths.push(coords);
        });
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: paths,
          map: null,
          visible: false
        });
        polys.push(poly);
      });
      mapPolies.set(city, polys);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle', function() {
        //console.log(map.getCenter().lat());
        //console.log(map.getCenter().lng());
        centerMarker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
        
        for (var entry of mapPolies.entries()) {
         entry[1].forEach(function(polygon) {
           var inside = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(map.getCenter(), polygon);
            if (inside) {
              console.log(`Map center inside polygon of ${entry[0]} city`);
            }
          });
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap&libraries=geometry" async defer></script>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am most grateful. Thank you so much.